# passing parameter recursion c++ (Letter Combinations of a Phone Number)

Tags: c++, recursion, parameter-passing

The problem is as follows.

Given a digit string, return all possible letter combinations that the number could represent.

A mapping of digit to letters (just like on the telephone buttons) is given below.

Input:Digit string "23"

Output: ["ad", "ae", "af", "bd", "be", "bf", "cd", "ce", "cf"].

I used backtracking but can't figure out why answer one is wrong....Guess I'm not familiar with how recursive calls work on passed params.

Can someone help me? Thanks a lot!
Wrong:

```
class Solution {
public:
    const vector<string> keyboard { " ", "", "abc", "def", // '0','1','2',...
        "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };

    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
        int len =digits.size();
        vector<string> res;
        string combo;
        bt( res, combo,digits, len, 0);
        return res;
    }

    void bt(vector<string> &res, string combo, string digits, int len, int i)
    {
         if (i==len)
         {
             res.push_back(combo);
             return;
         }
         int idx = digits[i]-'0';
         if (idx<0||idx>9)
             return;
         string tmp = keyboard[idx];

         int s=tmp.size();

         for (int j=0; j<s; j++)
            {
                combo.push_back(tmp[j]);
                i++;
                bt(res,combo,digits,len,i); 
            }

    }
};
```

Correct:

```
class Solution {
public:
    const vector<string> keyboard { " ", "", "abc", "def", // '0','1','2',...
        "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };

    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {
        int len =digits.size();
        vector<string> res;
        string combo;
        bt( res, combo,digits, len, 0);
        return res;
    }

        void bt(vector<string> &res, string combo, string digits, int len, int i)
        {
            if (combo.size() == len)
            {
                res.push_back(combo);

                return;
            }
            int idx = digits[i] - '0';

            string tmp = keyboard[idx];

            int s = tmp.size();

            for (int j = 0; j<s; j++)
            {
                bt(res, combo + tmp[j], digits, len, i+1);
            }
        }
};
```

I later found that using BFS is more intuitive to me and make my code more concise. Or what are better methods to write this without recursion? Thank you again!

```
class Solution {
public:
    const vector<string> keyboard { " ", "", "abc", "def", // '0','1','2',...
        "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqrs", "tuv", "wxyz" };

    vector<string> letterCombinations(string digits) {

        vector<string> res(1, "");
        string combo;

        int n=digits.size();
        vector<string> tmp;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            int m = keyboard[digits[i]-'0'].size();
            int rsize =res.size();
            for (int k=0; k<rsize; k++)
            {
                string ts = res[k];
                for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
                   {
                    res[k] = res[k] + keyboard[digits[i]-'0'][j];
                    tmp.push_back(res[k]);
                    res[k] = ts;
                   }
            }
            res = tmp;
            tmp.clear();
        }
        return res;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your loop here:

```
for (int j=0; j<s; j++)
{
    combo.push_back(tmp[j]);
    i++;
    bt(res,combo,digits,len,i); 
}
```

Let's say `tmp` is `"abc"`, what happens as you walk through your loop? First you `push_back('a')` and increment `i`... and then you `push_back('b')` and increment `i` again! You need to *backtrack*:

Hard way:

```
for (int j=0; j<s; j++)
{
    combo.push_back(tmp[j]);
    i++;
    bt(res,combo,digits,len,i); 
    combo.erase(i);
    --i;
}
```

Easier way:

```
for (int j=0; j<s; j++)
{
    bt(res,combo + tmp[j],digits,len,i + 1); 
}
```

Easiest way: recognize that `combo.size() == i` is an invariant and remove one variable:

```
for (int j=0; j<s; j++)
{
    bt(res,combo + tmp[j],digits,len); 
}
```

Which is why the "correct" solution you posted works, you are not failing to backtrack.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I still haven't quite/fully grasped backtracking and recursion even after I've spent so much time on it. I did find out what happened when I debugged step by step but can't figure out why the correct answer works.

Comment: Do you happen to have a good resource/book to read to learn it better? Thanks again!

Comment: @HappyCoder Nothing beats debugging experience. The correct answer works because in the loop, you're recursing with `"a"`, then `"b"`, then `"c"` whereas in your original attempt you're recursing with `"a"` , then `"ab"`, then `"abc"`. Do you see why they do different things? Do you see understand why only the former is correct? Sometimes it helps to just start with ultra simple cases: `letterCombinations("2")` had better give you 3 things back right?

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in

> combo.push_back(tmp[j]);

It`s correct for j == 0, but wrong for j != 0.

For example if j == 1. You`ll put to the bt function combo + tmp[0] + tmp[1] instead of combo + tmp[1].